# Best way to INSERT from CSV file into two 1 to many related MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm using PHP & MySQL

I have 2 tables with the following layouts:  (there are other fields not relevant to this issue)

`QUESTIONS
Q_ID, int, auto incrementing, primary key
Question, varchar(255)`

`ANSWERS
A_ID, int, auto incrementing, primary key
Q_ID, int
Key, varchar(255)
D1, varchar(255)
D2, varchar(255)
D3, varchar(255)
D4, varchar(255)`

I have a CSV file with the following layout:

`NULL, Question, Key, D1, D2, D3, D4  --  The NULL is for the Q_ID autoincrement field.`

I want to insert data from a CSV file into 2 related tables, `Questions` and `Answers`, joined with a one to many relationship.  Note that: 
     NULL & Question go into the Questions table (1 row)
     Key, D1, D2, D3, & D4 go into the Answers table, but as separate records, each with a    Q_ID that links back to their matching question.

I have a file which reads the CSV and creates an `$array` which is working properly.

If I loop through the `$array` to create a single `INSERT` statement  with a compound `VALUES` clause so I insert all the questions in one query, i.e.,

```
INSERT INTO Questions 
    (Q_ID, Client_ID, Question, Key, D1, D2, D3, D4)
VALUES 
    ('$arr[0][1]', '$client_ID', '$arr[0][2]', '$arr[0][3]', '$arr[0][4]', '$arr[0][5]', '$arr[0][6]'' )
    ('$arr[1][1]', '$client_ID', '$arr[1][2]', '$arr[1][3]', '$arr[1][4]', '$arr[1][5]', '$arr[1][6]'' )
    ('$arr[2][1]', '$client_ID', '$arr[2][2]', '$arr[2][3]', '$arr[2][4]', '$arr[2][5]', '$arr[2][6]'' )
    ('$arr[n][1]', '$client_ID', '$arr[n][2]', '$arr[n][3]', '$arr[n][4]', '$arr[n][5]', '$arr[n][6]'' );
```

In a multi-user environment, can I count on the autoincrement `Q_ID` field being consecutive for these records, even if there are many of them?  Will doing this as a transaction take care of it?  If I can be sure of consecutive `Q_ID`s, I can be much more efficient by doing far fewer queries.  Or is it counter productive to worry about performance of this type?

I'll then be able to compute the 1st `Q_ID` number by subtracting the number of rows inserted from the `last_insert_id` gathered after the insert executes.  I'll use it, incrementing it for each new row, in creating the `INSERT`s into the Answers table.

I can't test this in my single user development environment.  There, of course, the `Q_ID`s are always consecutive.

If I can't count on the Q_IDs being consecutive, it seems I'll have to do one insert into "Questions", get `last_insert_id`, and then do a multi-`VALUES` clause `INSERT` into Answers for each row in the CSV.

Though I don't show it here, I'll use mysql_real_escape_string to clean this user submitted data in either of these 2 approaches.

Or is there a better way?

arheops suggests below that I create a temp table to avoid using many queries.  I understand that reasoning, but do not understand his explanation for how to `INSERT` the multiple records in Answers for each record `INSERTed` into Questions.

Comment: Try looping and string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Best way is create temporary table same as csv file, after that create insert/select statment to fill your tables.

Note, serial(autoincrement) value is not always one-by-one. In conccurent environment can be +2 or +3 difference.

Usually i do like this:

1) import all in one table

2) do
  insert into table1(field1,field2,...fieldn) select field1,field2,... fieldn from temp_table;

3) after that do join of table1 and temp_table to got IDs and create select for insert into table2.

Note, for speedup join need create index on join column(question text?)

Comment: OK, I guess I use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to get the data into the temp table?  At what point do I clean the data in this user submitted CVS file.  And if I have an index on the temp file and still do 2 separate inserts, will this be faster, or just easier?

Comment: Do insert in form of  insert into tab1(field1,field,...fieldn) values (1,2,...n),(11,22, .. nn)...; so check it on that step. or do Load data, but that require special privileges.  Faster will be becuase you do select into each table in bulk. that last_insert_id is not so fast(every time new query).

Comment: I don't understand.  Once I have the data in the temp table, where the question, key and all distractors are fields in the same record, how do I create the INSERT commands you say to use?

Comment: you need create 2 selects: first for got insert into first table, second for got insert into seconds with lookup(using join) for IDs in first one. If both quaries created carefully, it will work much faster then your variant with alot of small queries.